# compare two filenames and extract differences

Tags: bash, filenames

I have two files with almost identical filenames:

```
/home/104800-001-001/H27VNDSX3_104800-001-001_GCCTATCA-CGACCATT_L002_R1.extracted.fastq.gz
/home/104800-001-001/H27VNDSX3_104800-001-001_GCCTATCA-CGACCATT_L002_R3.extracted.fastq.gz
```

How can I extract in bash ONLY the different characters?

Desired output:

```
1 3
```

Edit:

- Always the same length
- Take into account only differences in _R[0-9]

Comment: What should happen if the strings aren't the same length?

Comment: what's the expected output if there are multiple differences ... put each set of differences on a new line, or append on a single line of output? if consecutive characters are different do we still list as single-character differences or should they be combined into a single set of multi-character differences (eg, `a b`, `1 3`, `X Y` vs `a1X b3Y`?)

Comment: They will always be the same length. 

In case there are more differences, only take into account the ones around *_R[0-9]*

Comment: *only take into account the ones around `_R[0-9]`* -- that makes this a **completely** different question, and needs to be [edit]ed in, not added as a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Comparing Only An Interesting Subset

(Answering the question as-edited)

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

s1='/home/104800-001-001/H27VNDSX3_104800-001-001_GCCTATCA-CGACCATT_L002_R1.extracted.fastq.gz'
s2='/home/104800-001-001/H27VNDSX3_104800-001-001_GCCTATCA-CGACCATT_L002_R3.extracted.fastq.gz'

revision_re='_R([[:digit:]]+)[._]'

rev1=; rev2=;
[[ $s1 =~ $revision_re ]] && rev1=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
[[ $s2 =~ $revision_re ]] && rev2=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}

if [[ $rev1 && $rev2 ]] && [[ $rev1 != "$rev2" ]]; then
  printf '%s %s\n' "$rev1" "$rev2"
fi
```

---

#### Comparing The Whole String

(Answering the question as originally asked)

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

s1='/home/104800-001-001/H27VNDSX3_104800-001-001_GCCTATCA-CGACCATT_L002_R1.extracted.fastq.gz'
s2='/home/104800-001-001/H27VNDSX3_104800-001-001_GCCTATCA-CGACCATT_L002_R3.extracted.fastq.gz'
 
max_len=$(( ${#s1} > ${#s2} ? ${#s1} : ${#s2} ))
for (( idx=0; idx<max_len; idx++ )); do
  if [[ ${s1:idx:1} != "${s2:idx:1}" ]]; then
    printf '%s ' "${s1:idx:1}" "${s2:idx:1}"
  fi
done
printf '\n'
```